# Wrong filling importing .svg

Tags: import, color, path, svg

I'am trying to import a svg file in Blender, but the filling comes up all wrong.
[image]

The file comes from a vectorized .jpeg, it looks all good in inkscape, but some parts change filling color once imported in Blender.
The work flow works pretty well for other images, but when they become too complex this problem appears.
I tried to clean up all small and unnecessary paths in inkscape and combine all remaining paths: same result...

Thanks for any tips !

Comment: Watch for overlapping or intersecting segments and open paths

Comment: maybe try to scale it up in Inkscape before importing? Also, you can now vectorize an image in Blender itself: Add your jpg image as Reference, go in the header menu > Object > Trace Image To Grease Pencil